# Как выполнить действие после завершения потока

Tags: c++, многопоточность

```
void print()
{
    cout<<"Hello!!";
}
void print2()
{
    while(true) cout << "while";
}
void test()
{
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(200));
th = make_unique<thread>([&]() {
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(800));
    cout << "Connection is successful! Wait...";
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    cout << "Setting up the environment!";

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(400));
    cout <<"All is done!";

});
print();
if (0 != th.get())th.get()->join();
}
```

Как мне вызвать метод `print()`, который находится в области видимости `join()` после выполнения потока **th**. А так же, чтобы одновременно выполнялся метод print2()

```
int main()
{
    test();
    print2();
    cout<< "Hello 2222";
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: В смысле дождаться завершения потока? Непонятно, что вы хотите...

Comment: @Harry Да, после завершения потока **th** требуется вызвать функцию **exit()**. А получается, что она вызывается во время выполнения потока

Comment: Видимо автор хочет join, но не может этого принять.

Comment: @KoVadim Тогда у меня не будут выводиться сообщения по порядку с интервалом, а выведутся через какое-то время все вместе. И программа все это время неактивна

Comment: *Тогда у меня не будут выводиться сообщения по порядку с интервалом* — это еще почему? ну добавьте сброс `<< std::flush`... А программа может себе продолжать работать, а когда всю работу сделает — вот тогда пусть и вызывает `join()`. Не устраивает?

Comment: @Harry Если я вызову `join()` в конце программы, тогда,если я,например, захочу ее закрыть, а там будет что-то выполняться, она не закроется

Comment: Вы только что не хотели закрытия, пока не завершится поток... *после завершения потока th требуется вызвать функцию exit(). А получается, что она вызывается во время выполнения потока* — вы писали? Вы уж определитесь, что вы хотите, ясно, точно и непротиворечиво...

Comment: @Harry это в плане, почему мне этот метод не подходит. Я хочу, чтобы она закрылась после выполнения всех итераций, а так же, чтобы я сам мог ее закрыть

Comment: 1) нет необходимости вызывать `exit()` - перепишите программу так, чтобы она завершалась возвращением из функции `main` 2) чтобы дождаться завершения потока, следует использовать метод `join()` 3) если при этом нужно не просто ждать поток, а заставить его остановиться, то для этого следует реализовать соотв. механизм, хотя бы в виде атомарного флага, который бы регулярно проверялся в потоке.

Comment: @user7860670 То есть, чтобы остановить поток, мне надо использовать атомный флаг, а не `this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(400));`? Поменял на join

Comment: @Harry Я постараюсь переформулировать вопрос:
Вот у нас есть потоки: 1) Основной 2) какой-то поток с названием th
В потоке th что-то выполняется: выводятся сообщения, приостанавливается на какое-то время (аля нагрузка)
Как мне сделать так,чтобы: когда вызываю поток `th`, он выполнялся как и до этого, сейчас у нас вместо выхода из функции будет функция `print()`, которая просто пишет **Привет**.  В конце программы мы обращаемся к `join`. Как мне сделать так, чтобы `print` выполнился после потока th (он в области видимости join), мне надо именно, чтобы print была в обл. видимости join

Comment: `sleep_for` не останавливает поток, а заставляет системный планировщик потоков не выделять этому потоку процессорного времени в течении заданного периода. Поток останавливается, когда выходит из выполняемой функции (которая была передана в конструктор), а `join` как раз служит для ожидания этого момента. Если хотите переформулировать вопрос, то лучше отредактировать сам вопрос, а не писать в комментариях

Comment: @user7860670 отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Вы вызываете `test()` и `print2()` (функция, которая вообще не имеет выхода и не завершается!!!) *последовательно*, но хотите, чтоб они работали параллельно? Вы ждете остановки потока в `test()`, но до этого вызываете `print()`? Если запустите `test()`, **из которого уберете** `print()` и `.join()`, затем выполните `print2()` — только перепишете ее так, чтоб она завершалась, потом уже вызовите `.join()` для ожидания завершения потока, и затем `print()` — это будет то, что вы хотите? И вообще, почему бы вам не внести `print()` в поток последним вызовом? :)

Comment: @Harry в этом и суть, что есть ли возможность сделать так?

Comment: Так, как я написал? А почему нет?...

Answer (score 1):

Вот [это](https://ideone.com/LwDpF8) — похоже на то, что вы хотите?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void print()
{
    cout<<"Hello!!";
}

void print2()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        cout << "meanwhile...\n";
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(200));
    }
}

thread test()
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(200));
    return thread([&]() {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(400));
        cout << "Connection is successful! Wait...\n";
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(400));
        cout << "Setting up the environment!\n";
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(400));
        cout <<"All is done!\n";});
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    auto t = test();
    print2();
    t.join();
    print();
}
```